# Word VBA - Bold Paragraph If first character Is Numeric

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to make this macro go through all paragraphs and check if they start with a number, if yes, I'd like it to make all that paragraph Bold.
However, nothing happens, not even an error message.

```
Sub titles()

    For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If IsNumeric(Paragraph.Range.Words(1).Characters(1)) = True Then
            wcount = Paragraph.Range.Words.Count
            Paragraph.Range.Words(wcount).Font.Bold = True
            'MsgBox (wcount)
        End If
    Next Paragraph

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Paragraph.Range.Words(wcount).Font.Bold = True
```

will just bold the last "word".  Try:

```
Paragraph.Range.Font.Bold = True
```